# Matching one of several possible characters in a string

Tags: bash, scripting

In a bash (version 3.2.48) script I get a string that can be something like:

> 'XY'
>   ' Y'
>   'YY'
>   etc

So, I have either an alphabetic character **OR** a space (first slot), then the relevant character (second slot). I tried some variation (without grep, sed, ...) like:

> if [[ $string =~ ([[:space]]{1}|[[:alpha:]]{1})M ]]; then

and

> if [[ $string =~ (\s{1}|.{1})M ]]; then

but my solutions did not always work correctly (matching correctly every combination).

Comment: Please explain better what you need. Do you want to test if the string has a particular format (if so, which format)? Do you want to extract the "relevant character" from the string? Something else?

Comment: show examples - failed matches.

Comment: I need to match the `git status --porcelain` output. Can be something like: 'A ', 'AD', 'MM', "AM', ' M' etc. I am interested in cases where I have a 'M' as second character.

Comment: so the rule is "has either a space or a char" and them "one char at the end". and you want to get that last char?

Comment: Right. The @patrix solutions seems to achieve the desired result, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
if [[ $string =~ [[:space:][:alpha:]]M ]]; then
```

Comment: Thank you, but this one has the same issue I previously found: does not catch 'MM'. I do not know the reason.

Comment: @Max: I apologize. I omitted a colon (and you did, too). Please see my revised answer.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I forgot a colon in my code, thank you. The odd part is: the only version working in my bash is the @patrix 's (first) one: `if [[ ${string:1:1} == "M" ]]; then`

Answer (score 3):

```
if [[ ${string:1:1} == "M" ]]; then
    echo Heureka
fi
```

or (if you want to do it with patterns)

```
if [[ $string =~ ([[:space:]]|[[:alpha:]])M ]]; then
    echo Heureka
fi
```

or (even simpler)

```
if [[ $string == ?M ]]; then
    echo Heureka
fi
```

Comment: I've added a version with patterns as well. If your problem is solved, please accept the answer

Comment: Works for me with 3.2.48, are you retyping or using copy/paste?

Comment: Tried typing and pasting. The only version working is the `${string:1:1} == "M"` one...

Comment: Strange. Maybe some of bash's options are different than mine.

Comment: Could be the Shopt Builtin? There is a way to enable options for a script?

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` might help, it's set to on here. But the third method in my answer should work in all cases, there's nothing special in that one.

Comment: The only solution that I have not tried (and I was not aware of) is your first one. And is the only one catching correctly every combination here. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Without using regular expressions, simply pattern matching is sufficient:

```
if [[ $string == [[::upper:]\ ]M ]]; then
  echo match
fi
```

Given your example, you want `[[:upper:]]` rather than merely `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: Thank you @glenn jackman : good point. Unluckily even this one does not works in my bash. The only solution giving me the exact result is `${string:1:1} == "M"` . I guess there is something I am missing about that...